# Gradle is not closing the port after stop the application

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

In Java, I am using *Spring* and *Gradle* and having the following issue (that I can't find the answer for!)

I am getting this error again and again when trying to compile...

```
   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
    > Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

    Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

MORE CLUES:

- The first time I open intelliJ, it works. Then it doesn't work again
- I am closing the app properly (click the red square), it is not that.
- The process using the port 80 is "java", so java is listening correctly...
- ...but it remains open even after closing the app
- If I close and open intelliJ, it works, but after stop the app is says:

> The daemon will cancel the build.
>   Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.5-rc-2-all.zip'.
>   12:57:48: External task execution finished 'bootRun'

Seems like *Gradle* is not closing properly my app, and it only works one time, then the port remains open forever even if I click stop (well, until I close *IntelliJ*!).

Here is my project in Github:

https://github.com/RicSala/project5countries

I have red EVERYTHING out there to fix it, but nothing helps...

Please help! :)

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to

1. Select `Run/Debug Configuration`(right side of top bar, click on your project name dropdown menu) and  select `Edit Configurations` in dropdown window
   [image]
2. Enable`Single instance only`checkbox
   [image]

Or you can manualy disable running app by pressing red box Stop on top bar (or Ctrl+F2)

Comment: That checkbox is already checked and I click the read square everytime to close the app, but somehow it remains open and using the 8080 port.

Comment: @Ric your project works perfectly fine for me, try to clean build or maybe even recreate it. 1 more thing i can think of is idea can hang for some reason and you will see processing in the bottom right menu. Click on it and force shutdown. you can actually run your project from console without Idea to see that it is not gradle fault: `gradle bootRun` and `Ctrl+C` to shutdown

Comment: @warren, thanks for your help.

I know it is something about Gradle or Idea, not the code: others can use it perfectly.

I have already uninstall idea and reinstall it, but it does not fix it.

I try to run it from my console, but the console says "command not found"

I also cleared the caché of idea and restart it. Nothing.

It is quite frustrating (and really common as I am seeing in stackoverflow).

Any other idea??